# Unpack variadic parameters for a template template function?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
// some arbitrary function 
template<typename T>
void log( T&& obj )
{
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;    
}

// arbitrary transformation
template<typename T>
T convert(T&& obj) { 
     return obj; 
}

template<template <typename> typename F, typename... T>
void callOn( F<T> func,  ///  issue: what's the type of func?                 
             T&&... params)
{
    func(std::forward<T>(convert(std::forward<T>(params)))...);
}

int main()
{   
    callOn(log, -1, -2.0);      
     return 0;
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Compiler complains: no matching function for call to 'callOn(, ..>).  Why ?

Update: suppose log is not unary function

```
template<typename T>
void log(T&& value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void log(First&& f, Rest&&... rest)
{
    std::cout << f << ",";
    log(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

callOn takes type "template " which doesn't match the type of log?  How to specify the type of func?

Comment: Meta meta programming?  We must go deeper!

Comment: wild guess: have you tried `template <typename...> typename F`?

Comment: @Philipp : That was my thought as well, but then the question makes little sense, as `callOn(log, -1, -2.0);` would attempt to pass two arguments to `log`, which is unary.

Comment: @ildjarn if log also accepts variadic params, how should callOn be defined?

Comment: Say `template <template <typename...> F, typename ...Args> void callOn(F<Args...> f, Args... args);`

Comment: @KerrekSB that doesn't work.  compiler complains: no matching function for call to 'callOn(<unresolved overloaded function type>, ..>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function object. Here's a compilable example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Log
{
    template<typename T> void operator()(T&& t) { 
        std::cout << t << std::endl; 
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Rest> void operator()(T&& t, Rest&&... rest)
    {
        std::cout << t << ", ";
        (*this)(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
};

template<typename T>
T convert(T&& obj) {
     return obj;
}

template<typename F, typename... T>
void callOn(F funcobj, T&&... params)
{
    funcobj(std::forward<T>(convert(std::forward<T>(params)))...);
}

int main()
{
    callOn(Log(), -1, -2.17, "abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The inner `std::forward` (wrapping the call to `convert`) is not needed and will likely interfere if it's intended that some overload of `convert` does special things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the syntax of `template <typename> typename F` is correct, and Standard specified in 14.3.3/1 that "A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be the name of a class template or an alias template", not a function template. If you want to pass a function template, you can declare the parameter as a pointer to function:

```
template<typename... T>
void callOn( void (*func)(T&&...params),
             T&&... params)
{
    //same as before
}
```

And when `callOn(log, -1, -2.0);` is called, the type of `T` is not deduced from `log` but from {-1, -2.0} to be {int, double}, then `func` is initialized from the pointer pointed to `log<int, double>(int&&, double&&)`.

Comment: Is it possible to express the function pointer as a std::function?

Comment: void (*func)(T&&...) works, but std::function<void(T&&...)> func does not.  Compiler complains that it cannot resolve overloaded function 'log' based on conversion to type 'std::function<void(const int&, double&&, ...)>'

Comment: You're right that `template <typename> typename F` is not correct, but your rationale is wrong -- `template <typename> class F` is indeed valid, it just requires the use of a templated functor rather than a function template.

Comment: Yes, that's valid template template-parameter syntax, and I said that it only accepts a class template argument.